# how to colorless images in android programmatically?

Tags: android, imageview

how can I colorless imageview programmatically . something like when users drag an image and see preview image instead of orginal image. thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: no , something like when you click on application icon in your application list

Comment: I update may question whit example

Comment: So, do you mean Brighter?

Comment: thanks for replay , this is exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an ImageView more transparent, use ImageView.getBackground().setAlpha(int);

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make imageview colorless or transparent use this.

```
 imageview.getBackground().setAlpha(255); // start from 0 to 255.
```

OR

```
 imageview.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```